# How do you select values from a table using php oop?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm trying to select some values from a MySQL table like this :

```
<?php
$this_id=(55,66,77);

$cate= find_by_sql('select * from tages where id in ( "'.$this_id.'") '); 
//function find_by_sql() get  values and put in array ()
?>
<?php foreach($cate as $cates1): ?>
<?php echo $cates1->tage_name; 
// tage_name is var in class 
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But, it's only selecting where the id is 55.

Comment: You need to make it as an array `$this_id= array(55,66,77);`

Comment: You can replace all of the funtion calls by method class, but the simple fact of the matter is that you're query probably is mixed in with markup judging by the closing and opening tags). Your code might _use_ classes, but that doesn't make it an OO project

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm afraid I'll have to disagree, since he's not using prepared statements a string litteral of numbers separated by commas is the right way to write it :). it should be `'55,66,77'`

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier You may be right, but that was just a comment. You may want to post that same one in the "answer" below, unless they've got it right. I won't argue with you on that point ;-) I should have probably said: *"You **may** need to make it as an array"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to be like this.

```
<?php
$this_id = "55,66,77";

$cate= find_by_sql('select * from tages where id in ( ' . $this_id . ') '); 
//function find_by_sql() get  values and put in array ()
?>
<?php foreach($cate as $cates1): ?>
<?php echo $cates1->tage_name; 
// tage_name is var in class 
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: is there any way with out implode because  values $this_id 55,66,44 from other table

Comment: I updated my code above based on your previous comment.

Comment: vary good thanks man :) problem solve .

Answer (score 0):

since you're using quotes around your variable, I assume this is not a prepared statement. In that case, you have to actually present a string for your sql to be valid. just change that line:

```
$this_id=('55,66,77'); // notice the single-quotes
```

Comment: the problem is $this_id is get values from other table and his values in the filed : 55,66,77

Comment: maybe   foreach not work good with mysql commend i writing  ?

Comment: meh. the problem is you have not pasted exactly your code. We had no way of knowing that `$this_id` came from another table and it really changes everything. Anyway check the question your's is a duplicate of, you will learn how to do this

Comment: Yes  i sorry  my question  not clear because there many code i cant put in here .

Comment: Don't put it all, just the relevant line `$this_id`

Comment: i make the code like this : <?php $cate= tages::find_by_sql("select * from tages where id IN (".$article->cateid.")  "); ?> and it solved my problem .. i am happy now :)